# Pandas - Proper Use of Apply Function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas frame "df" as follows:

```
    col1 col_group
0    1    1
1   -1    0
2   -2    0
3    4    2
4    2    1
```

I am trying replicate the values in 'col1', except I want to modify the values in 'col1' if they are in either 'col_group' 0, or 2. The modification would just be to multiply the existing values by 50%. I need to do this on 1MM+ rows, so I am wondering if there is an optimal way to generate my new column?

so my desired output would be:

```
  col1 col_group New
0    1    1      1
1   -1    0      -0.5
2   -2    0      -1
3    4    2      2
4    2    1      2
```

I am currently using a for loop, but thought there might be something faster in pandas.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your desired output and show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

```
    df['new_col'] = df.apply( lambda x: x['col1'] * .5 
                              if x['col_group'] in (0, 2) else x['col1'], 
                              axis=1)
```

Comment: Worked great. knew apply was the route, but did not think about lambda.

Answer (score 2):

## `pandas` `boolean` math

- `isin([0, 2])` gives `True`/`False`
- `div(-2)` turns `True`s to `-.5` and leaves `False` as `0`
- `add(1)` makes former `True`s to `.5` and `False`s as `1`

---

```
df.assign(New=df.col1 * df.col_group.isin([0, 2]).div(-2).add(1))
```

## `numpy.where`

```
df.assign(New=np.where(df.col_group.isin([0, 2]), df.col1 * .5, df.col1))
```

---

***both yield***

```
   col1  col_group  New
0     1          1  1.0
1    -1          0 -0.5
2    -2          0 -1.0
3     4          2  2.0
4     2          1  2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try boolean indexing.

```
df['col2'] = df['col1']
df['col2'].iloc[:][(df[col_group]==0) | df[col_group]==2)] /= 2
```